# Linking to javascript in a view subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view folder called 'HelloWorld', inside it I have another folder called 'table' with stuff inside it, I have something located here: table/media/js/jquery.js under the helloworld directory, I've set it to 'copy always' and its build action i s'Content'.

In the index of the view control I do this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="table/media/js/jquery.js")></script>
```

But for some reason it can't find it, if I try to manually go to it via the URL (i.e. http://localhost:XXXX/HelloWorld/table/media/js/jquery.js) the server still can't find it.

Any ideas how I'm supposed to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View folder is not browsable for security reasons, then you cannot serve files like your javascript file.

See the web.config inside the View folder, the handler BlockViewHandler does this,
create a similar structure within the content folder if you need to organize files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have created the following folder: `~/HelloWorld/table/media/js/jquery.js` where `~` is the root of your web site I would recommend you using url helkpers in order to generate proper url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/HelloWorld/table/media/js/jquery.js")")></script>
```

On the other hand the `Views` folder is a special folder in which you should put only your MVC views and not static files such as css and javascript that are intended to be served directly on the client.